# Access $scope from DOM in production?

Tags: angularjs

According to [this article](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes) (and a few others) one of the most common mistakes a developer can make when using Angular is:

> **Common Mistake #1: Accessing The Scope Through The DOM**
>
> There are a few optimization tweaks recommended for production. One of
>   them is disabling debug info.
>
> DebugInfoEnabled is a setting which defaults to true, and allows for
>   scope access through DOM nodes. If you want to try that through the
>   JavaScript console, select a DOM element and access its scope with:
>
> `angular.element(document.body).scope()`
>
> It can be useful even when not
>   using jQuery with its CSS, but should not be used outside of the
>   console. The reason being that when $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled
>   is set to false, calling `.scope()` on a DOM node will return undefined.

However, there are certain times when using Angular that a developer needs to access the scope outside of angular.

Is there another, recommended way of getting back "in scope"?

Comment: well you should use https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive to manipulate the DOM and use the scope elements then pass it upwards or downwards to the controller or child directives

Comment: yeah it is the only way .

Comment: _"there are certain times when using Angular that a developer needs to access the scope outside of angular"_ - Name one situation where this is necessary. Code that works outside of Angular has no idea of Angular. So why should there be a need to access a scope?

Comment: to make a call to compile() to inject dynamically loaded html into an exsting, parsed, angularJS page.

Comment: @zeroflagL Example of such a situation: I'm setting up analytics for a client. We want to pull shopping cart data without having to modify the original source code. This data is used to track ROI for the ad campaigns that we're running for the client.